# Header function is working on local server but not working online

Tags: php, header

I have got the following codes which are used for logout on proozpaddpage.php.
Header function works perfectly fine on XAMPP local server but the codes are not working online on my server and it returns blank page on proozpaddpage.php .
It should go to proozplogin.php.

I cannot understand why?

```
session_start();
require 'connect.ini.php';
```

/* IF The login Session has not started it should go back to login page. */

```
if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']){
  header('Location:proozplogin.php');
  exit;
}
```

/*LOG out SECTION*/

```
 if (isset($_POST['logout'])){
   session_destroy();
   header('Location: proozplogin.php');
   setcookie('cieo','',time()-1);
   setcookie('bdks','',time()-1);
   exit;
 }
```

```
<form action="proozpaddpage.php" method="post">
           <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" >
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out this line? `require 'connect.ini.php';`

Comment: Add **ini_set('display_errors',1)** to the beginning of the file.  Be sure to remove it after you have found the problem.  Or check the error log.